# How to get Arraylist Value and Store into another arraylist

Tags: java, android, android-intent

> I know this is silly but i am stuck this problem.i have try this but
>   not get desired result so i am ask this question: My question is

scenerio:1

```
  ArrayList<String> f = new ArrayList<String>();
        f.add("a");
        f.add("b");
        f.add("c");

        ArrayList<String> s = new ArrayList<String>();
        s.add("a");
        s.add("a");
        s.add("a");
        s.add("b");
        s.add("b");
        s.add("b");
        s.add("c");
        s.add("c");
    s.add("c");
```

> Now i want common value first arraylist and second arraylist
>      And i want result is like:

```
ArrayList<String> temp = new ArrayList<String>();//this is temp arraylist to store but here i didt use it
```

> ```
>    ___
>     a
>    ___
>     a
>     a
>     a
>    ___
>     b
>    ___
>     b
>     b
>     b
>    ___
>     c
>    ___
>     c
>     c
>     c
> ```

and saw like this .how can i solve this freinds Thanks in Advance freinds.

Comment: If your Lists are supposed to be ordered, ArrayList by not be a good choice for your implementation.

Comment: @MrSmith42 i have two for loop  one for s arraylist and second for f arraylist .. but i want when "a" value come so they can store into "a" arrylist.. same as "b" and "c".... if any suggestion how to i solve my problem..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
temp.addAll(f);
temp.addAll(s);
Collections.sort(temp);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int i=0;i<arraylist.size();i++){
templist.add(arraylist.get(i));
}
```

That should do it